# Geometric interpretation on an algebraic geometry problem

Tags: algebraic-geometry

Let $\mathcal{K}$ be an algebraically closed field and $n\geq 1$.

I've prooved that an ideal $\textbf{m}\subset \mathcal{K}[X_1,...,X_n]$ is maximal if and only if $\textbf{m}=(X_1-a_1,...,X_n-a_n)$, with $a_1,...,a_n\in \mathcal{K}$.

I need to interpret this result geometrically. Any suggestion is appreciatte.

Comment: Since $K$ is algebraically closed, you can take polynomials to be distinct functions $K^n\to K$. Then the elements of $m$ are those polynomial functions which vanish at the point $(a_1\dots,a_n)$. In fact the point is completely determine by $m$.

Answer (score 2):

This means that the only closed points of the topological space $X = \textrm{Spec}(\mathcal{K}[X_1,...,X_n])$ are the points coming from $\mathcal{K}^n$. Note that this space is not only a topological space, but also an *[affine scheme](http://www.math.uchicago.edu/~may/VIGRE/VIGRE2009/REUPapers/Ullery.pdf)*.